# Ajax jquery not posting form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I click the submit button on my form my registration page refreshes without the form data being posted to my database.

My HTML markup looks like this -

```
  <form id="reg">
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="color: white; text-align:center" for="username">Username</label>
  <input style="color: #C0C0C0;" type="text" name = "username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="color: white; text-align:center" for="password">Password</label>
  <input style="color: #C0C0C0;" type="password" name = "password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="color: white; text-align:center" for="email">Email</label>
  <input style="color: #C0C0C0;" type="text" name = "email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
</div>
<button type="submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

And my jquery code -

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  $('#reg').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault 
    $.ajax({
      url:'script/register.php',
      data: $(this).serialize(), 
      type:'POST',
      success:function(results) {
        $(".result").html(results);
      }
    });
  });

  </script>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. The page refreshes and I see the forms variables and values in the url bar. Any help with the above is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `preventDefault` is a method, hence you have to call it: `e.preventDefault` -> `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax: preventDefault is a function.

```
 $('#reg').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() <---- Here fails 
    $.ajax({
      url:'script/register.php',
      data: $(this).serialize(), 
      type:'POST',
      success:function(results) {
        $(".result").html(results);
      }  
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi Albeis, thanks for your reply. I have made the above change but now when I click the submit button nothing happens.

Comment: Analizing your code, after the preventDefault, which is stoping the default behaviour of the form submit, you should check: If data is filled properly, check the network tab of your browser to check if Ajax is sent to the script/register.php. Any error on the console? The answer solve the question, but now it should be another question :)

Comment: On the network tab it displayed - Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function. I managed to resolve this by adding the full version of jquery-3.3.1. Still no data is being posted. My php script posts correctly without the ajax

Comment: You mean on console tab, Check the network tab? Is the $.ajax making the request? Is it sending the params correctly?

Comment: $.ajax is making the request and the params seem to be sending correctly. Maybe the problem stems from my php script? Although it posts correctly without the ajax

Comment: Check your php script then ;) please check the answer as correct. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ajax code with the following

```html
<script>
    $('#reg').on('submit', function(e) {
          
        $.ajax({
            url:'script/register.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
               $(".result").html(results);
            }
         });
        return false;
       });
</script>
```

You should return false to prevent page refresh.